# Add computed column in a SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, view, calculated-columns

how can i add a computed column in SQL view in design mode?

I have column Sale and Tips and would like to add a column Total.

Example

```
Sale  | Tips | Total 
5     | 2    | 7
6     | 4    | 10
```

It's a query with 3 tables - Sales are in table Shop, Tips in table Customer and I would like to add the new column to the actual View, that acts like a query for these three table.

I've tried to add

```sql
CAST(SUM (Sale + Tips) AS INT)
```

I've put alias as Total. But it's not working. I'm new to sql so maybe the code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Personally, I suggest learning to write the SQL for your objects. The designer is a tool best avoided.

Comment: As for the problem, if you have an aggregate function (`SUM` in this case) you'll need to ensure you have a `GROUP BY` clause. Though I don't see why you need `SUM` here, when you're performing row level addition.

Comment: `SUM` is for aggregating values across *multiple* rows. You're already adding your two values together with `+`.

Comment: So is there a function i can use to add and calculate rows ?

Comment: @LexieHoang, just remove `SUM` and add a column alias to calculate the value for the current row: `CAST(Sale + Tips AS INT)  AS Total`

Answer (score 1):

IT is better if you use Tsql code

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TBL
ADD Total AS CAST((Sale + Tips) AS INT)
```

why you have `SUM` function I dont realy know